# Pipe params into script

Tags: bash, pipe, sh

Can I pipe parameters into a script downloaded using curl and have the script accept them as $1, $2 etc.. Trying to make this say Hello world

```
$ curl mysite.com
echo hello $1

$ echo world | curl mysite.com
echo hello $1

$ echo world | $(curl mysite.com)
hello $1
```

Comment: Why do you want to pipe parameters to a script rather than putting the value in front ? `./hello.sh $(echo "world")`
In this particular example, this is a useless use of the command `echo`.

Comment: I'm actually pulling the script in from curl.  curl http://<mysite>.com downloads the text *hello $1*

Comment: sorry, but I still don't understand what do you actually meant ! if `curl` downloads a script that contains `hello $1`, then like I mentioned, you could still execute `./hello.sh <some argument>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pipe text from `curl` to `sh`.

```
curl http://example.com/ | sh /dev/stdin world
```

The `/dev/stdin` script name is not portable to platforms which do not have `/dev/stdin`, obviously.  You may work around that with something like

```
sh -c "$(curl http://example.com/)" _ world
```

The first parameter after `sh -c '...'` goes into `$0`, so the dummy parameter `_` is supplied for that.

Either way, unless you have complete confidence in the URL, this is massively insecure.  See e.g. http://blog.classicalcode.com/2012/11/curl-pipe-sh-exploit-proof-of-concept/

For testing without `curl`, you can simply replace `curl http://example.com/` with `echo 'echo "hello $1"'`, or just supply a static string on standard input.

```
sh /dev/stdin world <<<'echo "hello $1"'
```

(If your shell is not Bash, or you are stuck in the mid-1990s and Bash 2.x and Debian Potato are hot news, you can replace the `<<<'here string'` with a regular [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document).)